# Function based off of app version in package.json

Tags: node-webkit

I would like to run a function based of the version of my node-webkit app from the package.json file. How do I get this version number?

I'm not talking about:

```
process.versions['node-webkit'];
```

Which just shows the node-webkit version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the manifest as an object in nw, using `App`. Just extract the version there:

```
var gui = require('nw.gui');
var myAppVersion = gui.App.manifest.version;
```

See also https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/App#manifest